# JTextPane getText() return html tag in different order

Tags: java, html, swing, gettext, jtextpane

I am using JTextPane to store some HTML text:

```
private static final String HTML_STR = "<html><div>plot(<b><font color=#3775B9>X</font></b>,Y)</div><div>plot(<b><font color=#3775B9>X</font></b>,Y,LineSpec)</div></html>"

JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setContentType("text/html");
textPane.setText(HTML_STR);
```

After that, every time I call the textPane.getText(). the html content will show the html tag in different order occasionally. Like:

sometimes, < b> is inside of < font>:

```
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      plot(<font color="#3775B9"><b>X</b></font>,Y)
    </div>
    <div>
      plot(<font color="#3775B9"><b>X</b></font>,Y,LineSpec)
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

some other times, < font> is inside of < b>:

```
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      plot(<b><font color="#3775B9">X</font></b>,Y)
    </div>
    <div>
      plot(<b><font color="#3775B9">X</font></b>,Y,LineSpec)
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anybody explain a little bit for me why JTextPane behaviors like this? Is there any way to let JTextPane return the same order constantly?
Thanks!

Comment: *"sometimes, < b> is inside of < font>:"*  What's the problem?  In semantics and effect, they are identical.

Comment: I need also create a unit test for this output, they are not identical, right? And I also want to understand is this a normal behaviors for JTextPane?

Comment: *"they are not identical, right?"*  Textually no, but in end result, yes they are identical.  One way to 'fix' this 'problem' you see is to define a (CSS) class that describes both the color and weight of the text, wrap the text in a single `span` and apply the class to it.